# is there an elegant way to transfer a subset of one deque to another?

Tags: c++, deque

By using boost perhaps or another way?

I want to create a function, to grab a subset of deque `d` from (and including) index iStart to index 0, into a new deque, but also to set that those values in `d` to 0. I thought about this:

```
std::deque<int> CreateSubset(std::deque<int>& d, int iStart )
{
   int iSubsetSize = iStart+1;
   std::deque<int> subset(iSubsetSize); // initialise a deque of a certain size.

   std::deque<int>::iterator it = d.begin();

   subset.assign (it, d.begin()+iStart+1);

   for(;it != d.begin()+iStart+2; it++)
   {
     *it = 0;
   }  
   return subset;
}
```

But it looks horrible to me - is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it in C++11. I believe the code is fairly elegant, and I don't think there is anything particularly inefficient about it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename ForwardIt>
std::deque<int> extract(ForwardIt from, ForwardIt to)
{
  using std::make_move_iterator;

  std::deque<int> d2(make_move_iterator(from),
                     make_move_iterator(to));
  std::fill(from,to,0);

  return d2;
}
```

The `extract()` function template takes two forward iterators, moves the content between them to a newly created deque and sets it to 0 in the original.

The template as written makes two assumptions:

1. Although the source iterators may refer to anything, the destination is always a deque;
2. The default value you want to reset the original elements to is 0.

Both assumptions can be relaxed by introducing further template parameters or function arguments.

As you can see, I use `std::make_move_iterator` to convert the input iterators to move iterators, thus causing the elements to be moved (rather than copied) to the destination. As long as these are `int`, it won't really make a difference, though.

I use the `std::fill` algorithm to set the original elements to 0.

This is how you could call this function template:

```
int main()
{
  /* Creating d. */
  std::deque<int> d
  { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 };

  /* Extracting the first three elements into a new deque. */
  auto d2 = extract(begin(d),begin(d) + 3);

  /* Printing the results. */    
  std::cout << "d:\n";
  for (const auto &elem : d)
    std::cout << elem << ',';

  std::cout << "\n\nd2:\n";
  for (const auto &elem : d2)
    std::cout << elem << ',';

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you issue a make_move_iterator does it not invalidate the old iterators ? Can you explain why you had to do the fill with zeroes ?

Comment: @gansub In the example given in the question there are no "old iterators", but if there were any, then no, they would not be invalidated. However, after the elements are moved out of the deque, those old iterators would point to elements that might have changed in value. It is not predictable what the values of those elements will be. The reason I fill them with zeroes is that the question explicitly asked for that. There is no need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Container concept requires container types to define `iterator` and `const_reference` it is even possible to have jogojapan's answer a little more generic without having more than one template parameter.

```
template <typename Container>
Container extract(typename Container::iterator from, 
                  typename Container::iterator to, 
                  typename Container::const_reference replacement)
{
  using std::make_move_iterator, std::fill;
  Container new_container(make_move_iterator(from),
                          make_move_iterator(to));
  fill(from,to,replacement);
  return new_container;
}
```

Where you can go for

```
deque<int> d { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 };
auto d2 = extract<deque<int>>(begin(d),begin(d) + 3, 0);
```

The downside is that template argument deduction won't work that nice anymore.

The benefit is that you can use the code for almost all STL containers like vectors, deque, list, forward_list, set, map ... since they all have at least a forward_iterator as their iterator type.
You can also specify a "default" replacement.

It would also be possible to use a pointer instead of a reference so you can decide whether you want to erase (passing nullptr) or replace the elements with a certain value (passing a valid pointer to a respective object).